# DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated while starting odoo15 on local

Tags: terminal, odoo, odoo-15

I installed odoo 15 on my local and installed all the dependances, but when i start my server it shows me a py warning and i am unable to solve this issue, any help will be much appreciated, the warning i am getting in my local is below:

> 2022-01-11 10:26:54,032 8202 WARNING ? py.warnings:
> /home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py:68:
> DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use
> packaging.version instead.
> File "core/odoo-bin", line 8, in 
> odoo.cli.main()   File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/cli/command.py", line 61, in
> main
> o.run(args)
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/cli/server.py", line 176, in
> run
> main(args)
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/cli/server.py", line 170, in
> main
> rc = odoo.service.server.start(preload=preload, stop=stop)
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/service/server.py", line
> 1286, in start
> load_server_wide_modules()
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/service/server.py", line
> 1196, in load_server_wide_modules
> odoo.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/modules/module.py", line
> 396, in load_openerp_module
> **import**('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/addons/base/**init**.py",
> line 5, in 
> from . import models   File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/addons/base/models/**init**.py",
> line 13, in 
> from . import ir_actions_report
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py",
> line 68, in 
> if LooseVersion(version) < LooseVersion('0.12.0'):
> 2022-01-11 10:26:54,033 8202 WARNING ? py.warnings:
> /home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py:73:
> DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use
> packaging.version instead.   File "core/odoo-bin", line 8, in 
> odoo.cli.main()
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/cli/command.py", line 61, in
> main
> o.run(args)
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/cli/server.py", line 176, in
> run
> main(args)
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/cli/server.py", line 170, in
> main
> rc = odoo.service.server.start(preload=preload, stop=stop)
> File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/service/server.py", line
> 1286, in start
> load_server_wide_modules()   File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/service/server.py", line
> 1196, in load_server_wide_modules
> odoo.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)   File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/modules/module.py", line
> 396, in load_openerp_module
> **import**('odoo.addons.' + module_name)   File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/addons/base/**init**.py",
> line 5, in 
> from . import models   File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/addons/base/models/**init**.py",
> line 13, in 
> from . import ir_actions_report   File "/home/itachi/Workspace/odoo_15/core/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py",
> line 73, in 
> if LooseVersion(version) >= LooseVersion('0.12.2'):
> 2022-01-11 10:26:54,154 8202 WARNING ? odoo.addons.base.models.res_currency: The
> num2words python library is not installed, amount-to-text features
> won't be fully available.  2022-01-11 10:26:54,181 8202 INFO ?
> odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on
> Uchiha-Madara:8069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in this [pull request](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/84097) and you need yo update your Odoo to latest version to fix it.